# select multiple images with pagination in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I wonder if anyone knows a jQuery plugin that meets the following characteristics:

- It show a list of images.
- This list can be paged (to avoid the scroll bar appears).
- It can select multiple images (with checkbox or in other way).

I found options like these:

- [multiselect](http://loudev.com/#demos): but it contains the scrollbar and the resulting size is too small, I need adjust better size (especially in width).
- [fcbklistselection](http://www.emposha.com/javascript/fcbklistselection-like-facebook-friends-selector.html): it has similar "disadvantages".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. The [smartpagination](http://www.egrappler.com/jquery-pagination-plugin-smart-paginator/) jquery plugin allows to include "elements" that can be set on demand, in my case, the checkbox and the image (contained in a *li*), with the **dataelement** option.